# -1 vote for questions about Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Why did I get -1 vote for both questions I asked regarding Stack Overflow?
Is it something like bullying on this site?

Comment: @Keyur: Read the FAQs page, and then post your questions to meta.stackoverflow.com where they belong.

Answer (score 13):

The first rule of Stack Overflow is that you don't talk about Stack Overflow on Stack Overflow.

> If you want to talk about the site itself, please don't do it here. Visit our meta-discussion site where you can talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, suggest a feature, or generally discuss how Stack Overflow works.

OK it's not quite the *first* rule, but it *is* mentioned quite early on in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Questions about Stack Overflow is what meta.stackoverflow is for, and that's why we are here now.

Comment: That and the "If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead" in the sidebar of the "Ask Question" page.

Comment: @MB You watch too many movies :-)

Answer (score 0):

See best-voted answer to your question. I don't see why you're getting downvoted here on SO, as your question is on topic (even though it's a FAQ, it seems mean to downvote if well-intentioned).

Comment: It's a loaded question - *"Is it something like bullying on this site?"* - that's almost an invitation for downvotes.